# C#. Как запретить save file dialog в webbrowser при получении json контента?

Tags: c#, webbrowser

У меня в программе происходит post запрос через компонент webbrowser. В ответе приходит json контент, но браузер возвращает его не в webBrowser1.DocumentText, а создает диалоговое окно сохранения файла и ждет подтверждения действия. Возможно ли отменить создание диалогового окна, либо указать как именно получать json содержимое, то есть как содержимое страницы, а не файл?

Answer (score -1):

Программа не знает как и с чем открываешь этот формат. Для предотвращения открытия надо дать ей знать что делать с типом файла. Если я не ошибаюсь, то этот контрол базируется на IE- надо его запустить и в опциях настроить действие для данного типа файла.

Comment: Попробовал запрет скачивания, все равно появляется окно, сообщающее о запрете.

Comment: Обязательно использовать web control, может можно обойтись HttpWebRequest'ом?

Comment: Пришлось его использовать, на странице сайта, с которым работает программа, несколько сотен чекбоксов и каждое значение передается в параметрах запроса, руками их собирать нереально. Пришлось браузер юзать: заполнил элементы страницы где нужно, нашел кнопку, нажал и порядок)

Comment: Если это какая-то автоматизация, то удобнее будет её сделать в Selenium или ему подобных. В других случаях можно просто игнорировать возврат(POST) и продолжать работу после редиректа (отослал и забыл)